# Any foss apps on Linux that contain the print booklet feature of Adobe Acrobat Reader?

Tags: linux, pdf, printing, software-rec, adobe-acrobat

I have been using the [Print Booklet](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/print-booklets-acrobat-reader.html) -function of Adobe Acrobat Reader on Windows. However the program does not have a Linux version, see [download page](https://get.adobe.com/reader/otherversions). Also I don't see the option on `Evince`.

Are there any apps that have this functionality?

Comment: what does this "print booklet" function do?  you can't expect linux users to know the details of some mystery function in a program that only runs on windows.

Comment: I edited your question, replaced inappropriate code markings with a link to Adobe page explaining the booklet option. This kind of functionality has been available at least on Windows printer drivers for years, so I'd start looking from there.

Comment: Does your printer driver have such a feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can run [`pdfbook2`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/texlive-extra-utils/pdfbook2.1.en.html) (package texlive-extra-utils) on the PDF file.

> pdfbook2 - Create print-ready PDF files from some INPUT PDF files for booklet
> printing. The resulting files need to be printed in landscape/long
> edge double sided printing. The default paper format depends on the
> locale and is choosen by pdfjam. It can be set with the --paper
> option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **LibreOffice Draw** for print in booklet. It's simple!

Click on the file using the right button and "*open with*" LibreOffice Draw. Then, *FILE* > *PRINT* and down the tab to *BROCHURE*.

But **DON'T FORGET**: in "*paper sides*", choice "*print on both sides (SHORT edge)*".

I hope I help you.